# How to automatically update the specified files when merging pr on github

Tags: github, bots, pull-request

```
test-repo
    /file1.txt
    /other.txt
    /...

fork-repo
```

**test-repo** is the original repository, **fork-repo** is forked from **test-repo**.

Now add the following requirement to the **test-repo**：

1. All pull requests for **test-repo** must not contain **file1.txt**.
2. When any pull-request is merged, the content of **file1.txt** is automatically changed according to the custom rules.

That is, the content of **file1** is never edited by people, nor is it allowed to be edited by people. When each PR is merged, the file is automatically changed <For example, add a PR record or something (for example only, actually for other purposes)>; **The submitter equivalent to **file1** is always the bot.**

For the first requirement, a detection judgment can be added to the pull-request;
If the changed file list of pr contains file1, the check fails.

But the second requirement, I did not think of a good solution;
because that file1 can not be changed in the pr,
but also through the bot to change file1, feeling quite contradictory.

Do you guys have any solutions to share?